# .Net 3.5 Asynchronous Socket Server Performance Problem

Tags: c#, asynchronous, synchronization, sockets

I'm developing an Asynchronous Game Server using .Net Socket Asynchronous Model( BeginAccept/EndAccept...etc.)

The problem I'm facing is described like that:
When I have only one client connected, the server response time is very fast but once a second client connects, the server response time increases too much.

I've measured the time from a client sends a message to the server until it gets the reply in both cases. I found that the average time in case of one client is about 17ms and in case of 2 clients about 280ms!!!

What I really see is that: When 2 clients are connected and only one of them is moving(i.e. requesting service from the server) it is equivalently equal to the case when only one client is connected(i.e. fast response). However, when the 2 clients move at the same time(i.e. requests service from the server at the same time) their motion becomes very slow (as if the server replies each one of them in order i.e. not simultaneously).

Basically, what I am doing is that:

When a client requests a permission for motion from the server and the server grants him the request, the server then broadcasts the new position of the client to all the players. So if two clients are moving in the same time, the server is eventually trying to broadcast to both clients the new position of each of them at the same time.

EX:

- Client1 asks to go to position (2,2)
- Client2 asks to go to position (5,5)
- Server sends to each of Client1 & Client2 the same two messages:
- **message1: "Client1 at (2,2)"**
- **message2: "Client2 at (5,5)"**

I believe that the problem comes from the fact that Socket class is thread safe according MSDN documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx. (NOT SURE THAT IT IS THE PROBLEM)

Below is the code for the server:

```
/// 
/// This class is responsible for handling packet receiving and sending
/// 
public class NetworkManager
{
    /// 
    /// An integer to hold the server port number to be used for the connections. Its default value is 5000.
    /// 
    private readonly int port = 5000;

    /// 
    /// hashtable contain all the clients connected to the server.
    /// key: player Id
    /// value: socket
    /// 
    private readonly Hashtable connectedClients = new Hashtable();

    /// 
    /// An event to hold the thread to wait for a new client
    /// 
    private readonly ManualResetEvent resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    /// 
    /// keeps track of the number of the connected clients
    /// 
    private int clientCount;

    /// 
    /// The socket of the server at which the clients connect
    /// 
    private readonly Socket mainSocket =
        new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    /// 
    /// The socket exception that informs that a client is disconnected
    /// 
    private const int ClientDisconnectedErrorCode = 10054;

    /// 
    /// The only instance of this class. 
    /// 
    private static readonly NetworkManager networkManagerInstance = new NetworkManager();

    /// 
    /// A delegate for the new client connected event.
    /// 
    /// the sender object
    /// the event args
    public delegate void NewClientConnected(Object sender, SystemEventArgs e);

    /// 
    /// A delegate for the position update message reception.
    /// 
    /// the sender object
    /// the event args
    public delegate void PositionUpdateMessageRecieved(Object sender, PositionUpdateEventArgs e);

    /// 
    /// The event which fires when a client sends a position message 
    /// 
    public PositionUpdateMessageRecieved PositionUpdateMessageEvent
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// 
    /// keeps track of the number of the connected clients
    /// 
    public int ClientCount
    {
        get
        {
            return clientCount;
        }
    }

    /// 
    /// A getter for this class instance.
    /// 
    ///  only instance.
    public static NetworkManager NetworkManagerInstance
    {
        get
        {
            return networkManagerInstance;
        }
    }

    private NetworkManager()
    {}

    /// Starts the game server and holds this thread alive
    /// 
    public void StartServer()
    {
        //Bind the mainSocket to the server IP address and port
        mainSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));

        //The server starts to listen on the binded socket with  max connection queue //1024
        mainSocket.Listen(1024);

        //Start accepting clients asynchronously
        mainSocket.BeginAccept(OnClientConnected, null);

        //Wait until there is a client wants to connect
        resetEvent.WaitOne();
    }
    /// 
    /// Receives connections of new clients and fire the NewClientConnected event
    /// 
    private void OnClientConnected(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref clientCount);

        ClientInfo newClient = new ClientInfo
                               {
                                   WorkerSocket = mainSocket.EndAccept(asyncResult),
                                   PlayerId = clientCount
                               };
        //Add the new client to the hashtable and increment the number of clients
        connectedClients.Add(newClient.PlayerId, newClient);

        //fire the new client event informing that a new client is connected to the server
        if (NewClientEvent != null)
        {
            NewClientEvent(this, System.EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        newClient.WorkerSocket.BeginReceive(newClient.Buffer, 0, BasePacket.GetMaxPacketSize(),
            SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(WaitForData), newClient);

        //Start accepting clients asynchronously again
        mainSocket.BeginAccept(OnClientConnected, null);
    }

    /// Waits for the upcoming messages from different clients and fires the proper event according to the packet type.
    /// 
    /// 
    private void WaitForData(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        ClientInfo sendingClient = null;
        try
        {
            //Take the client information from the asynchronous result resulting from the BeginReceive
            sendingClient = asyncResult.AsyncState as ClientInfo;

            // If client is disconnected, then throw a socket exception
            // with the correct error code.
            if (!IsConnected(sendingClient.WorkerSocket))
            {
                throw new SocketException(ClientDisconnectedErrorCode);
            }

            //End the pending receive request
            sendingClient.WorkerSocket.EndReceive(asyncResult);
            //Fire the appropriate event
            FireMessageTypeEvent(sendingClient.ConvertBytesToPacket() as BasePacket);

            // Begin receiving data from this client
            sendingClient.WorkerSocket.BeginReceive(sendingClient.Buffer, 0, BasePacket.GetMaxPacketSize(),
                SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(WaitForData), sendingClient);
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            if (e.ErrorCode == ClientDisconnectedErrorCode)
            {
                // Close the socket.
                if (sendingClient.WorkerSocket != null)
                {
                    sendingClient.WorkerSocket.Close();
                    sendingClient.WorkerSocket = null;
                }

                // Remove it from the hash table.
                connectedClients.Remove(sendingClient.PlayerId);

                if (ClientDisconnectedEvent != null)
                {
                    ClientDisconnectedEvent(this, new ClientDisconnectedEventArgs(sendingClient.PlayerId));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Begin receiving data from this client
            sendingClient.WorkerSocket.BeginReceive(sendingClient.Buffer, 0, BasePacket.GetMaxPacketSize(),
                SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(WaitForData), sendingClient);
        }
    }
    /// 
    /// Broadcasts the input message to all the connected clients
    /// 
    /// 
    public void BroadcastMessage(BasePacket message)
    {
        byte[] bytes = message.ConvertToBytes();
        foreach (ClientInfo client in connectedClients.Values)
        {
            client.WorkerSocket.BeginSend(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, SocketFlags.None, SendAsync, client);
        }
    }

    /// 
    /// Sends the input message to the client specified by his ID.
    /// 
    ///
    /// The message to be sent.
    /// The id of the client to receive the message.
    public void SendToClient(BasePacket message, int id)
    {

        byte[] bytes = message.ConvertToBytes();
        (connectedClients[id] as ClientInfo).WorkerSocket.BeginSend(bytes, 0, bytes.Length,
            SocketFlags.None, SendAsync, connectedClients[id]);
    }

    private void SendAsync(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        ClientInfo currentClient = (ClientInfo)asyncResult.AsyncState;
        currentClient.WorkerSocket.EndSend(asyncResult);
    }

    /// Fires the event depending on the type of received packet
    /// 
    /// The received packet.
    void FireMessageTypeEvent(BasePacket packet)
    {

        switch (packet.MessageType)
        {
            case MessageType.PositionUpdateMessage:
                if (PositionUpdateMessageEvent != null)
                {
                    PositionUpdateMessageEvent(this, new PositionUpdateEventArgs(packet as PositionUpdatePacket));
                }
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

The events fired are handled in a different class, here are the event handling code for the PositionUpdateMessage (Other handlers are irrelevant):

```
    private readonly Hashtable onlinePlayers = new Hashtable();

    /// 
    /// Constructor that creates a new instance of the GameController class.
    /// 
    private GameController()
    {
        //Start the server
        server = new Thread(networkManager.StartServer);
        server.Start();
        //Create an event handler for the NewClientEvent of networkManager

        networkManager.PositionUpdateMessageEvent += OnPositionUpdateMessageReceived;
    }

    /// 
    /// this event handler is called when a client asks for movement.
    /// 
    private void OnPositionUpdateMessageReceived(object sender, PositionUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        Point currentLocation = ((PlayerData)onlinePlayers[e.PositionUpdatePacket.PlayerId]).Position;
        Point locationRequested = e.PositionUpdatePacket.Position;


       ((PlayerData)onlinePlayers[e.PositionUpdatePacket.PlayerId]).Position = locationRequested;

            // Broadcast the new position
            networkManager.BroadcastMessage(new PositionUpdatePacket
                                            {
                                                Position = locationRequested,
                                                PlayerId = e.PositionUpdatePacket.PlayerId
                                            });


        }
```

Comment: It looks like you may only be processing the packets you receive on a single thread.

Comment: I haven't read the code, but a couple of questions? Are clients ignoring their own move messages - they should ignore them? How often are you broadcasting messages?

Comment: @sblom- I believe not, the events are fired from the callback function "WaitForData". I assume that this callback function is executed in a different thread when packets arrive simultaneously to the server

Comment: @chibacity- No, clients are not ignoring their own move messages. They interpret their own move messages as a "movement request granted" message(since collision detection is performed by the server).

I broadcast messages whenever a client request to move is granted. In the above code, I removed these details. You can safely assume that every movement request by the client is granted by the server and accordingly a broadcast is done.

Comment: This question is instructive for a very different reason.  There's a point where the documentation starts to interfere with the readability of the code.  You're well past it.  You'll have to edit this wall of text to get anybody to read it.

Comment: @Hans Passant- You mean I should remove the inline comments?

Comment: That will at some point in time make the maintainer of your code happy, no doubt.  The attention span at SO is no more than 30-35 lines of code.  Read this: http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've edited my post and removed lots of useless code and comments. Take a look :)

Comment: Please don't put tags into the subject line.

Comment: If the server needs to send info to all clients, why don't you broadcast it as UDP instead of individually sending? You'll run into a scaling problem if your game has several players.

Comment: yea, you right. However, for the tight time constraints I'm having there is not enough time to design my own handshaking procedure to guarantee correct inorder delivery since UDP will not do this for me. For the time being, I am not demanding high scalability, later on I can just remove this network manager class and replace it with a more scalable one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move

```
//Start accepting clients asynchronously again 
mainSocket.BeginAccept(OnClientConnected, null);
```

To right after the line

```
ClientInfo newClient = new ClientInfo
```

So that you don't block on accepting new connections longer than necessary.

> believe that the problem comes from
>   the fact that Socket class is thread
>   safe

That shouldn't be relevant for your scenario.

Did you remember to set the NoDelay property on your socket to disable Nagling?

Comment: Why do you suggest NoDelay? It should [almost never be used](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/intermediate.html#disable-nagle). Out of the dozens of protocols I've written, I turned it off on only one (and that's only because it was a serial protocol slapped onto TCP/IP, instead of a protocol *designed* for operating on TCP/IP).

Comment: Regarding the accept issue, you are right but this is not my problem at all. I am having issues with moving 2 clients simultaneously and not simultaneous connections. You can safely assume that clients are connected one after the other so no blocking occurs.

Comment: I suggest NoDelay because his goal is not to move lots of data, it's to move small chunks of data very quickly. NoDelay is designed for that. The article you link to, Stephen, makes this point, so you're actually supporting my point even if you didn't intend to.

Comment: Nagle was the problem indeed